# Finding the hidden treasure

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, online-algorithms, upper-bound

Let's assume I am trying to find a hidden treasure.

The treasure is hidden at an uknown position x. We know that the position x of the treasure is somewhere on the integer axis (in other words x is an integer). In order to find the treasure I have to take with me a detector. The detector can spot the treasure only if it is above it.

My starting position is the 0 point and I can move back and front until I cross the treasure, so that my detector can track it. I am always moving on the integer line. Which is the most efficient way to move through the axis in order to track the treasure?? I have to find an algorithm that allows me to find the treasure by covering a distance $O(|x|)$

**My approach**: After some consideration, I think that the most efficient way to find the treasure is the following: Starting from 0 I move front until I reach number $2$. Then I move back until I reach number $-2^2$. Then I move front until I reach number  $2^3$. Then I go back again until I reach number $-2^4$ and so on...

However, I am having difficulties on proving that there is a constant $c$ (for which I have to calculate an upper bound) so that my algorithm is going to help me find the treasure at $c |x|$ moves at most.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am new at the computer science stack exchange so I am not sure about the tags. Correct them or add more if necessary.

Comment: @narekBojikian Thanks for the response! I am still a bit confused. Could you provide a more extensive answer?

Comment: @narekBojikian Yeah I got that! It would be really helpful if u could write down a more analytical answer! Thanks again!

Comment: My comments were not well formulated that is why I deleted them but you can find the full answer now

Comment: This is known variously as the lost cow problem, the cow-path problem, and similar names. It’s a standard example in the field of online algorithms. You can find a lot of pertinent material online.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Didn't know that! Your referrence helped a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is known variously as the *lost cow problem* or the *cow-path problem*, and is a standard example in online algorithms. The algorithm you describe is 9-competitive, which is optimal for deterministic algorithms. For randomized algorithms the competitive ratio is roughly 4.6. See for example a [writeup](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.270&rep=rep1&type=pdf) apparently by Rudolf Fleischer.

Comment: So 9-competitive algorithm means that the constant $c$ that i need to upper bound is 9 right?

Comment: Right, that’s what it means.

Comment: So, the proof of the Theorem 2 in the following link: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.270&rep=rep1&type=pdf) shows that the algorithm is 9-competitive and solves my problem, right ?

Comment: Yes. And the following theorem shows that "9" is optimal.

Comment: Yeah I see..And I could also use the notation $|x|$ instead of $x$ at the proof since we use the distance from 0 and we dont care about the actual position of x (positive or negative) right?

Comment: Yes, the situation is symmetric with respect to the two half-axes forming the X axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You really helped me solve the problem.

Comment: I would like to ask one last question that I just noticed. Shouldn't we have a strict inequality at the proof of Theorem 2 (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.270&rep=rep1&type=pdf), so that we have to use $o$ notation? Isn't it  $9f_i + \epsilon  - 6 < 9(f_i + \epsilon )  $ instead of $9f_i + \epsilon  - 6 \leq 9(f_i + \epsilon )  $ ? (since $\epsilon$  is a small positive integer)

Comment: Little o notation has a different meaning, and doesn’t apply here. Besides, if $a<b$ then in particular $a\leq b$.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest a similar strategy. Note that your strategy yields a constant factor better than the one presented here but the proof is more technical.

Let us divide the strategy in rounds $1, 2, \dots$, where in round $i$ we go $2^{i-1}$ steps to the right, then we go back to the center and we repeat the exact same to the left.
This means we go one step to the right then back to the middle and one to the left and back again then two to the right and two to the left then 4 to the right and so on. The total number of steps is upper bounded by

$$4\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\left\lceil \log x\right\rceil} 2^i$$
$$\leq 4 \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log x + 1} 2^i$$
$$\leq 4\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log (2x)} 2^i$$
$$\leq 4 \cdot 2^{\log(2x)+1}$$
$$=  4\cdot 2^{\log(4x)}$$
$$= 16x,$$
where the factor 4 in the first line means going to the right $2^i$ steps then back to the center and repeating on the left side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Which is the total number of steps i have to follow in this case? (which has the upper bound you mentioned) Is it $$1+1+1+1+2+2+2+2+4+4+4+4+... = 4\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\left\lceil \log x\right\rceil} 2^{i}$$ ??

Comment: Yes exactly,  and you stop when you find it. Note that for any number x there is an exponent of 2 not less than x but less than 2x.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, for any positive integer $x$ there is a non-neg. integer $k$ such that $x \leq 2^k < 2x$

Comment: @Yeah I see. In my case what would be the total number of steps I have to follow? $$2+2+2^2+2^2+2^3+2^3+...= \sum\limits_{i=2}^{\left\lceil \log x\right\rceil} 2^i$$ ??

Comment: Almost but the problem is you do not finish at $\left\lceil \log x\right\rceil$, since it might be the case that $x = 2^{2k} + 1$ where we go additional distance to the left and then again double as much to the right. I think you can achieve a factor of $8$ with your algorithm but I am not sure if you can do better.

Comment: Of course, we can break once we find the treasure so you can also use this fact to make it maybe only a factor of $4$ or so? Try to do the math your self it is a good exercise. Find the a rande for the sum and find an upper-bound closed formula

Comment: Ok will try to do so! But even if I manage to find a smaller constant than 16 for the upper bound, the complexity of the algorithm is still the same (linear) $O(x)$ and I think your solution seems easier to understand and with a simpler mathematical proof.

Comment: It is not very important in your case. However, there is a whole branch of theory studying these kinds of problems where you don't have  all the information about the problem and you are looking for some guarantee compared to the optimal solution if you knew all the information from the beginning. For example, if you already knew x you will have to go exactly x steps meanwhile my algorithm goes in worst case 16x as proven above. Thus field is called online algorithms and they study the lower bounds of the reachable factors so going from 16 to 8 is also interesting in theory

Comment: The truth is that I am a beginner on this field and as a result I am not familiar with this kind of problems and their mathematical background. Your solution was very helpful and easy to follow. However, even if I tried, I can't calculate an upper bound for my own algorithm, which was my initial question. If u could do the math in this case I would be really grateful and I will accept the answer as well. In either case thank you very much for your time!

Comment: After some search I found this article: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.270&rep=rep1&type=pdf  . I think that the proof of Theorem 2 is what I am looking for. The constant $c$ that we were talking about seems to take the value 9. The lower bound seems more complicated. However, the upper bound is what I care about.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. Without loss of generality, suppose that $2^{2n-1} < x \le 2^{2n+1}$. Now, if you count the number of steps needed to find $x$ with your algorithm, you'll find out that it contains the sum of geometric progression which can be bounded by $2^{2n+3} = 16\cdot 2^{2n-1} = O(x)$ since $2^{2n-1} < x$.

Comment: Thanks for your response!Which is the exact number of steps needed to find x ? (that has the upper bound you mention)